# Dynamic Changing URL (Link Redirector) Service?

Tags: url, dynamic, redirect, url-shortener

I wanted to see if there is a service out there that can dynamically change a URL

Ex.  If I wanted someone to go to a landing page like www.handsomeman2015.com/landing2015 and I used a link shortner like bit.ly so I would provide the URL like bit.ly/ag95g and it would direct customers to

But I want to be able to change the URL extension to landing2016, landing2017 etc without changing the web link, is this possible?

Sorry if my question isn't using the correct terminology, as I'm a bit new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[Yourls](http://yourls.org/) seems to be an interesting option, if you don't mind installing the service on your own website. Additionally, tiny.cc seems to allow you to change the link through their API.

Answer (score 0):

[Linkredirector](https://linkredirector.com/) is a dynamic URL shortener that lets you change the destination URLs of your links. As long as you register an account you can login and edit your links.

Disclaimer, I work at Linkredirector.